# delphi windows service can't download file from internet

Tags: windows, delphi, service

i have a  windows service written in delphi,the service will  use to downloading a file from my website but it can't download the file,it doesn't thrown any exception also i change the destination path and the file to be download but the result was same,my firewall was off too,my project work properly in another PC that i test on it and in windows application my function works properly too, so what should be the problem ?
thx for ur time

Comment: When you say "can't download the file", how do you verify this if it doesn't throw an exception? Does it simply hang?

Comment: with the try except block..., in the excpet try to write the exception message on a text file

Comment: Where has the description for this problem gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normaly, under `LocalSystem`, a service **can't access network resources.**
You said it works with another PC, I can't explain why.
You said it works in another application, yes, because application is executed with current account.

The solution may be to execute the service under the `Network Service`account.
Check it to see if it fixes the issue !

Answer (score 1):

Services cannot access Network Resources, such as via UNC paths, without additional access rights applied.  But a service has unrestricted access to use TCP and UDP sockets.  I've written several services that connect to remote servers via TCP/IP and they work fine without extra configurations or access rights needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the access rights of the user the service runs under.

By default it is LocalSystem, which may not be allowed to access remote networks (i.e the Internet). Try running it under the same user you logged in as.

Hope this helps

Comment: thx but i said that it will work properly in another pc under the local system

Comment: my pc use a shared connection  to access to the internet

Comment: here is the exception when using c# service to download a file under the local system :
exception message:Unable to connect to the remote server
connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)

Comment: innerExeption :System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9666
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean

Comment: is it possible that the service can't use  the shared connection to access to internet ?  i know the windows service under the local system account can use shared connection to access to internet like sending email

Comment: ??? Using what? MAPI or SMTP? I believe it's MAPI, because SMTP would need to create an direct connection to the network (direct = under Local System account).

Comment: i use wininet dll to download, i know with smpt it will work on local system

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture and check the HTTP session, and understand if it is an issue at the transport level or something else.