# Service applications and com plugins

Tags: delphi, com

I have written a set of plugins which work fine in normal application. But when I try to use them in service application my service stops when it reach `CreateComObject` function.
Can I use COM plugins in service application?
This is code:

```
procedure TWCMService.CreateControllerList;
var
  List: TAutoFreeList<TController>>;
  i: integer;
  Plugin: IPluginInterfaces;
begin
  try
    List := TAutoFreeList<TController>.Create;
    DatabaseModule.IBDatabase1.Connected := true;
    DatabaseModule.SelectControllers(List);
    DatabaseModule.IBDatabase1.Connected := false;
    Plugin := CreateComObject(StringToGuid('{F2959AEC-644F-49E4-9012-B9B3BF34B43F}')) as  IPluginInterfaces;
    for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
      begin
        Plugin.Init(StringToGuid(List[i].PluginId));
        FAvailControllers.Add(CreateComObject(Plugin.GetCommunicationPluginGuid) as ICommunicationPlugin);
        FAvailControllers[i].Init(Self as IServiceApplication);
        FAvailControllers[i].SetMAC(List[i].ControllerMAC);
        MessageBox(0, 'Dodany', 'Uwaga', MB_OK);
      end;
    List.Free;
    FAvailControllersCurrentIndex := 0;
    Timer1.Enabled := true;
  except
    raise Exception.Create('WCM Serwis: Error Message');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Paste it in, select it, and then click on the {} button.

Answer (score 3):

Untested and just off the top of my head...You probably will find that you need to initialize COM (call coinitialize), this is normally done for you with a windows app (in application.Run or higher up the chain) with a service applett you won't have had this done for you, you will need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to initialize the COM library for each thread calling CoInitialize
Described here. http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2007/06/delphi-tips-and-tricks_20.html

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, you need to make sure COM is initialized. But that might not be the main reason. 
You're using Interbase and to connect to the database, it's probably communicating over the network with the database server. (Even if DB is on the same system!) But a Windows Service doesn't have network access by default so you must add a dependency to the service to the network functionality.
Your problem could be the same as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799123/delphi-windows-service-problem), making this one a duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

It could be something security related. Depends on your operating system. Services may run under another account. The rights of this account might not be sufficient to create the COM object you want. Just guessing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solution was simple. I had to insert CoinitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) in OnServiceStart event and Couninitalize in OnServiceStop event.

Answer (score 0):

Could your problem be similar to the one I experienced?
[EIntfCastError 'Interface not supported' when run as a TServiceApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195992/eintfcasterror-interface-not-supported-when-run-as-a-tserviceapplication/16439201#16439201)
When creating the object, i.e. `TComObjectFactory.Create` I changed the threading model from `tmSingle` to `tmApartment`. Then I unregistered and re-registered the server. Presto! Not quite sure why but it works for me.

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment below that you had got it working.