# EIntfCastError 'Interface not supported' when run as a TServiceApplication

Tags: delphi, com, windows-services

I'm having problems using a COM-object when I run my application as a Windoes Service, i.e. TServiceApplication. The exception EIntfCastError 'Interface not supported' is raised.

If I run the application as a normal Delphi app then it works fine, including if I run as a service using srvany.exe

```
type IMyInter = interface (IUnknown)
['{9E6B311E-C6D3-4687-B272-3FBE9DBC2DD6}']
//...
end;

type 
  TMyObject = class
  private
    FMyInter: IMyInter;
  published
    constructor Create(const ClassID: TGUID);
  end;

constructor TMyObject.Create(const ClassID:TGUID);
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  FMyInter := CreateComObject(ClassID) as IMyInter;  
  //.... 
end;
```

It seems like the error is raised after the call to CreateComObject when the result is going to be assigned to FMyInter. Both the application and COM-object are 32-bit. I'm running on Windows 7 64bit and using Delphi XE3. The COM-object has been registered with regsvr32.exe

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where is the class that implements IMyInter interface?

Comment: Have you tried taking srvany out of the picture by creating a new service application yourself and then adding just the code you need to reference the COM server? We have apps that can be started as a service or standalone (command line option to the app itself) and have no trouble using out of process COM dll's.

Comment: @iPath – TmyObject is the class that implements IMyInter.

Comment: @Marjan Venema - It's my service/standalone app that I'm struggling to get to work in service mode i.e it works in standalone mode. I'll try your advice on creating a new service application and only add the necessities. TTYL

Comment: @Lars it doesn't look like TmyObject imlements it? Your code declares a pure class that has nothing to do with interfaces. So it cannot be casted as IMyInter? It should be declared at least as: TMyObject = class(tInterfacedObject, IMyInter)

Comment: @iPath thanks for your help! I now realize I only provided info on the com-client (app/service) side of things.

Comment: @Marjan, thanks for your help. I stripped the code down to the bones and this helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem which resided on the COM-server side. When creating the object, i.e. TComObjectFactory.Create I changed the threading model from tmSingle to tmApartment. Then I unregistered and re-registered the server. Presto! Not quite sure why but it works for me.

```
...    
initialization
    TComObjectFactory.Create( ComServer, TMyComServerClass, Class_ComServerClassGUID, ‘My Com Server Class’, ‘My Descriptive text’, ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
```